# c# MySqlConnector query and FOUND_ROWS()

Tags: c#, mysql, mysql-connector

Foreword: I am pretty new to MySqlConnector for c#, and MySql in general.

The goal I would like to achieve is to execute a query, and then obtain the number of records returned in the SqlDataReader by using FOUND_ROWS.

Here is the code I am running:

```
    public MySqlDataReader Execute()
    {
        RecordCount = 0;

        mCommand = new MySqlCommand("SELECT a,b,c FROM TABLE my_table where field_x=hello", connection);

        MySqlCommand result_count_cmd = new MySqlCommand("Select FOUND_ROWS()", mCommand.Connection);



        try
        {
            // create mysql command and execute it
            mReader = mCommand.ExecuteReader();

            // get the number of rows returned by the query
            RecordCount = Convert.ToInt32(result_count_cmd.ExecuteScalar());

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error Running Query: " + mCommand.CommandText);
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }

        return mReader;

    }
```

The problem I am facing is that when trying to execute the FOUND_ROWS() query, it fails telling me that I cant create a new DataReader on the same connection being used by another non-closed reader. It sounds fair to me, is there any way that I can retrieve the number of rows returned by the query WITHOUT, running the very same query as SELECT COUNT [...] as a different DB Operation? Or is there a way to call the FOUND_ROWS query while the DataReader is still open?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:

```
 try
    {
      // create mysql command and execute it
       mReader = mCommand.ExecuteReader();
       int RecordCount=0;
       while (mReader.Read())
           { 
             ///do what you want with the result
             RecordCount++; //count number of rows returned
           }
     }
```

Comment: Hmm... mCommand stores the query to be executed, so, by reading mReader[0].ToString(), wouldnt I just read the the first field of the first record returned by the query? Thats the reason why I created 2 Commands: one (mCommand) holding the "real" query", and the second one (result_count_cmd), to to hold the FOUND_ROWS query. Am I missing something here ?

Comment: where do I get the records? I dont see any MySqlDataReader... Let me try to edit the code... so that maybe the question gets less confusing

Comment: `ExecuteReader` returns a fast, forward-only, set of records, and won't give you the record count. You could count the records as you go through the Reader; use `ExecuteNonQuery` as already suggested, or run an entirely separate query first to count() the records that will be returned. BTW 'hello' needs to be surrounded with apostrophes.

Comment: If you definitely need, or want, to return a DataReader then run a separate query first (using the same SQL criteria) to Count() the records. Personally, I think it is a bit of a contradiction to do this. With a DataReader the purpose is to iterate all rows once, quickly, and you could count the records while doing so, outside of your method.

Comment: I see both your points, but this was exactly what I didnt want to do for the following reasons:

Comment: 1. I would like to perform checks that the number of records is as expected, before starting to actually read the results.

Comment: 2. I would like to avoid that the table gets medofied between the count query and the real query, potentially leading to inconsistencies

Comment: So... in the end it appears the FOUND_ROWS() function of MySql cannot be used along with the DataReader